# Disproving big O polynomial inequality

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, computer-science

I am stuck on a simple question that asks me to disprove 
$$f(n)=10n^3−2n−10$$
is **not** $O(n^2)$ without using any properties of $O$-notation. If I were to solve this, how would I go about this. I do understand that:

We need to prove 
$$cn^2 < 10n^3−2n−10$$
 where $c$ being a positive integer. And next I need to manipulate the inequality but I am not sure how that would prove the inequality at hand?

Can anyone help me understand these type of equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $c>0$, for $n>n_0:=\max(c/7,2)$,
$$10n^3−2n−10=7n^3+(n^3−2n)+(2n^3−10)>7n\cdot n^2+0+0>cn^2$$
because $n^3>2n$, $2n^3>10$, and $7n>c$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your hint? how did you get 8n^3?

Comment: @Saad Is it clear now?

Comment: To be honest not really. i get that $$n^3 > 2n, $$n^3 > 10 but how does this relate to the question? Like the way i was thinking about it was manipulating the inequality and getting a value for n.

Comment: It is not necessary to "solve" the inequality. We have a "big" term $10n^3$ and we can split it to balance the other terms.

Comment: So i were to disprove this, then this would be the way to do it? Also now i understand what you did with the 10n^3.

Comment: Anyway, I edited my answer with another approach. Do you like the new one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59309/discussion-between-saad-and-robert-z).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean without using any properties of O-notion?

You can show that: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{10n^3-2n-10}{n^2} = \infty$

Comment: I just want to solve it by manipulating the inequality.

Comment: ok, I understand. then Robert Z gave you a nice answer for that :)
But keep in mind that using limits is usually a nice and easy way to show O-notions (and $\Omega$ notions as well)

Comment: We are still learning that in class. I am trying this question which we did in class but couldn't get the idea from our professor.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) says:

$$ f(x)=O(g(x)) \; x \to \infty \tag{W1} $$
is defined as
$$\exists M: \; \exists x_0: \; \lvert f(x) \lvert\le M\lvert g(x)\lvert,\; \forall x > x_0 \tag{W2}$$

If we replace $M$ and $x_0$ by 
$$C:=\max\{x_0,M\} \tag{W3}$$
 and get the simpler equivalent definition

$$\exists C: \;  \lvert f(x) \lvert\le C \lvert g(x)\lvert,\; \forall x > C \tag{W4}$$

If  we restrict $x$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and if $g(n) \ne 0, \; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$  we can set 
$$c:=\max\left\{\left\lvert \frac{f(1)}{g(1)} \right\lvert,
\left\lvert \frac{f(2)}{g(2)} \right\lvert,
\ldots,
\left\lvert \frac{f(\lfloor c\rfloor)}{g(\lfloor c\rfloor)} \right\lvert,
C\right\} \tag{W5}$$
and we finally get

$$\exists c: \;  \lvert f(n) \lvert \le c \lvert g(n)\lvert,\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \tag{W6}$$
if $g(n)\ne 0, \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

You cannot show something about the big $O$ notation without using its properties.

$$f(n)=O(n)\tag{1}$$

means,  that
$$\exists c \in \mathbb{R^+}:\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \; f(n)\le c\cdot n\tag{2}$$

The negation  of this sentence is

$$\lnot\;(\exists c \in \mathbb{R^+}:\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \; f(n) \le c\cdot n) \tag{3}$$
which is equivalent to

$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R^+}: \; \exists n  \mathbb{N}: \; f(n)>c \tag{4}$$

For our $f$ this means we have to show

$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R^+}: \; \exists n  \mathbb{N}: \;  cn^2 < 10n^3−2n−10\tag{5}$$
or
$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R^+}: \; \exists n  \mathbb{N}: \;  10n^3−cn^2-2n−10>0  \tag{6}$$

This is true, we can select
$$n:=c+2 \tag{7}$$
then we have
$$ 10n^3−cn^2-2n−10
\\= 10(c+2)^3−c(c+2)^2-2(c+2)−10
\\=9c^3+56c^2+114c+66\\
>0 \tag{8}$$
because $c>0$.

Comment: Should that not be there exists c such that there exists n...for the definition of big oh?

Comment: @Saad about what statement are you talking? (2)?

Comment: yes (2), i was just looking on the internet and it seems it should be "there exists" for both c and n and in negation it becomes "for every".

Comment: No, the inequality must hold for all $n$. "There exist an $n$ and there exist a $c$" such that a property holds does not make sense. You want not make a statement about the value of $f$ at a single $n$ but you want to make a statement how $f$ behaves on the whole (or almost the whole) set of natural numbers.

Comment: @Saad: added a link to wiki and some explanations. The previous comment  was to answer your question but I forgot to add your name.